# Entity Framework - select data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I haven`t got visible territory do you know why (in my LINQ)?

Example

```
 var student = (from s in ctx.Students
                where s.StudentName == "Student1"
                select s).FirstOrDefault<Student>();
```

Database (table Territories):

[image]

LINQ

[image]

LINQ with ctx have also problems

[image]

TerritoryId

[image]

Correct:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {

            using (var ctx = new NORTHWNDEntities())
            {

                var Territory = (from s in ctx.Territories
                                 where s.TerritoryDescription
                                       == "Student1"
                                 select s).FirstOrDefault<Territories>();
            }

            return View();
        }
```

Thanks all for your time! and help.

Comment: Do you mean your code is compiling but you can't see `Territory` in the design ? did you try refreshing the edmx, or deleting it and creating a new one ?

Comment: Shouldn't be `from s in ctx.Territories`?

Comment: Do you return anything in the view at all?

Comment: @Gert Arnold this is not problem. Problem is with LINQ. In my project .ctx is not visible I make all things step by step from this tutorial. http://entityframeworktutorial.net/querying-entity-graph-in-entity-framework.aspx#.US9DNUfXono  I know there are other way to take data from table but this example is very simple and I would like to use this way.

Comment: Do you create a variable like `using var ctx = new MyContext())`?

Comment: @Gert Arnold What I have to write to have access to ctx? becuase when I write MyContext() Resharepr ask me "Create class my Context"

Comment: try to rebuild you project. or restart your computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ctx` is not something that magically appears when you create a context diagram. To use your context you must instantiate it like so:

```
using(var ctx = new MyContext())
{
    var territory = ....
}
```

where `MyContext` should be replaced by the name of your context class.

Comment: what I have to add because MyContext() or MyEntity() is not visible.

Comment: Well, I don't know the name of your context class. See my addition.

Comment: public partial class NORTHWNDEntities : ObjectContext
    {} <- I understand NORTHWNDEntities I have to put

Answer (score 3):

Is it visible ctx in the context where you are doing the query?
The problem looks like you didn't create well an instance of your data context (ctx) or may be that variable (ctx) in not visible the that context.

Comment: you know I using VS 2010 create .edmx and now I would like to take data from Territoy using LINQ but ctx is not visible. Resharper tell me "create local variable ctx" what I have to do?

Comment: You could create the local variable, or you could also declare a private variable at controller level scope and then initialize that variable in controller's contructor. Then the variable will be visible in all your actions.

Answer (score 2):

Check the class to see if the property is marked as private.

Comment: access is public to this table.

Comment: I was refering to the TerritoryID itself, it could be marked as private and the Table as public.

Comment: I edtited my post can you look it?

Answer (score 2):

Shoul not be:

```
(from s in Territories where s.TerritoryID == "Student1" select s).FirstOrDefault<Territories>();
```